# SQL query for adding column value to compare with other column

Tags: sql, join, compare

I have two tables

```
table_inventory
    List item
    inventory_rack_key(primarykey)
    node_key
    rack_id
    inventory_item_key
    in_coming_qty,locked_qty
    quantity

table_item
    inventory_item_key(primary key)
    item_id,product_zone
```

The table example are provided here [DB TABLES](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AltIfHyzagUAdGVwTmE2SXdvMlNkOXBKcHZIaHJEZkE#gid=0)
I need query to find out those items for which **(net_qty)** i.e difference b/w sum of `in_coming_qty` & `quantity` & `locked_qty` is negative. arranged by `node_key,rack_id, item_id,net_qty`

**Note:** each distinct set `{node_key,rack_id, item_id,net_qty}` will have only 1 row in output.
For ex `:{node_key,rack_id, item_id}` = {ABD101,RK-01,562879} has 4 rows in **table_inventory**
but in output net_qty= -78(single row) .

The query I made is giving me result but can we do it in some other way?

```
SELECT l.node_key, 
       l.rack_id, 
       i.item_id, 
       ( SUM(l.quantity + l.in_coming_qty) - SUM(l.locked_qty) ) AS net_qty 
FROM   table_inventory l, 
       table_item i 
WHERE  l.inventory_item_key = i.inventory_item_key 
GROUP  BY l.node_key, 
          l.rack_id, 
          i.item_id 
HAVING SUM(l.quantity + l.in_coming_qty) - SUM(l.locked_qty) < 0
```

Comment: Why is the answer you have unacceptable?

Comment: @mwigdahl my answer is correct but is there some other way to do the same

Comment: If there's no immediate problem with your current solution (like inconsistent results, too slow etc.), you might consider posting it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, which is intended for such questions.

Comment: @AndriyM Sure I ll post it there too

Answer (score 4):

Not really. There is this minor variant:

```
select v.* from (
SELECT l.node_key, 
       l.rack_id, 
       i.item_id, 
       SUM(l.quantity + l.in_coming_qty - l.locked_qty) AS net_qty 
FROM   table_inventory l, 
       table_item i 
WHERE  l.inventory_item_key = i.inventory_item_key 
GROUP  BY l.node_key, 
          l.rack_id, 
          i.item_id
) v
where net_qty < 0
```

- which means that the `SUM` calculation only needs to be coded once, but you do still need to do a SUM.

Comment: Please also consider using ANSI `JOIN` syntax -- it will help insulate you against the possibility that an error in your `WHERE` clause might cause a cartesian `JOIN`.

Comment: Generally speaking, this is not the same. For example, if there are rows where `locked_qty` is NULL while `quantity` and `in_coming_qty` are not (or the other way round), the results of the two queries would be different. Still, those NULLs do not seem very likely, judging from the column names, and your argument about the SUM calculation stands too.